# Mac OS X remove line from multiple files

Tags: macos, grep

I'm attempting to remove a line from several hundred files. The following does exactly what I need but, it doesn't save changes (as expected).

```
$ grep -v meow src/files
```

I've seen that appending `>` to the end of a given command will specify where the output buffer should save but, does this work for multiple files?

So I'd like to know if there's an elegant way to mass edit via the terminal. All of the examples I've come across using `awk` or `sed` only provide solutions for editing one file at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is using the following Perl one-liner:

```
perl -i.bak -n -e 'print unless /meow/' src/files
```

This should do in-place editing of multiple files. The originals are saved in `.bak` files.

Comment: Thanks! I received the following error using your recommendation though.
`Can't do inplace edit: src/files is not a regular file.`

Comment: So, what is `src/files` exactly? Is it a directory? (You didn't say that.) If it is, then use `src/files/*` to select all files in that directory.

Comment: Thanks! This worked fantastically! And if I don't want to save the originals in a `.bak` file?

Comment: If you don't want `.bak` files, use just `-i` without mentioning `.bak`.

Comment: Thanks Greg, this is super helpful! Does the complexity change if needing to traverse nested directories?

Comment: Not much. You can replace `src/files` with `$(find src/files -type f)` which will select all the files in `src/files` and its subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to do a similar operation with sed:

```
sed -i .bak '/meow/d' src/files/*
```

Perl got its `-i` option from sed, after all.  Note that to use no backup file, you need an explicit empty extension with at least some versions of sed:

```
sed -i '' '/meow/d' src/files/*
```

Comment: Both the sed and the perl solutions are not specific to Mac OS X.  Surely this has been covered previously, either in Stack Overflow or in the Unix/Linux exchange.